# When first user make a change,the another user will be able to view this change

Tags: c#, oracle, mapinfo

in my system, I have oracle database and mapinfo DAT files. I have two different users in system. When first user make some changes,he can see this changes in oracle database and his mapinfo dat files but another user can see only in oracle database and can't see in mapinfo. So second users have to load workspace in project, to see this changes.
When first user make a change,the another user will be able to view this change  . 
Or,when first user make a change, currently,
second user will be able to get a warning like 'some users make a change in system.'
 How can I do this. What are your suggestions..

Comment: If mapinfo files can be opened in shared lock mode by your application (I guess that it is some kind of embedded database) consider running your application on terminal server so that changes to dat files are made by all users to only one set of files. The other way is some kind of file-based synchronization, but that will work only if changes are made sequentially not simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

We need some more information.

What kind of project is this?

Signal-R could be a solution for you bounded to triggers in the database
http://signalr.net/

Comment: in my project,authorized users on the system, can add, edit, query, advanced reporting   electrical objects on the map, with the support of electrical and graphical results .in a nutshell,It is a map application which can be added,updated,reported.vs..